# Use decimalformat in slf4j or logback to pad or ident numbers so they align right

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I have this log statement in SLF4J (with Logback below it):

```
        logger.info("{} has {} depots, {00} vehicles and {} customers with a search space of {}.", ...);
```

And I get this output:

```
A-n62-k8 has 1 depots, 8 vehicles and 61 customers with a search space of 10^108.
A-n63-k10 has 1 depots, 10 vehicles and 62 customers with a search space of 10^111.
```

But I want this output, which add extra space padding/indentation:

```
A-n62-k8  has 1 depots,  8 vehicles and 61 customers with a search space of 10^108.
A-n63-k10 has 1 depots, 10 vehicles and 62 customers with a search space of 10^111.
```

Is this possible with SLF4J?

Comment: But how will you be able to predict if the variables you are giving will only be of certain size? Like it is possible that as the program grows in future, there might be A-n63-k10000 for the first var. Number of customers might become 10000 or a million. So, either you leave it as is or you send the input vars with necessary padding(which is too much effort to put in on a log as it will take your time and processing to pad every input).

Comment: I am expecting to submit some sort of padding size. I was hoping something like {##0.00} would work.

Comment: @dronidze's answer looks to be the only solution. Please post if you find any answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems no. You should use String.format(...) for each argument which has to be with extra spaces. Something like this

```
logger.info("{} has {} depots, {} vehicles and {} customers with a search space of {}.", String.format("%-9s", "A-n62-k8"), "1", String.format("%-2s", "8"), "61", "10^108");
```

Comment: Agreed, but this is slower because the String.format() cost occurs even if info logging isn't on.

Comment: You will also have SonarLint warnings https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2629   And for a good reason. If you have a log.debug you will be executing the padding even if debug is off

Comment: @Geoffrey De Smet: yes, it will be slower. This problem (with performance) will be solved in SLF4J 2.0 (it is available now in SLF4J 2.0.0-alpha1).

It is solved by "Support the lambda expression in the Logger". See details: https://jira.qos.ch/browse/SLF4J-371